# JQuery add link to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a way in JQuery to select text from the html document and add a link around it?

Many Thanks,
Nav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like below.

```
var txtN=$("#div").text();
var htmlStr=<a href="">txtN</a>
```

then inject htmlStr in the HTML...

you can use the absolute positioning to set the position.

Answer (score 13):

You can use jQuery's `wrap` function:

```
$(someSelector).wrap(function() {
   var link = $('<a/>');
   link.attr('href', 'somewhere_far_far_away');
   link.text($(this).text());
   return link;
});
```

Comment: @jacom , just want to know , the above code adds href html inside someselector....??

Comment: @jacom , great i learn one new thing this morning, thanks +1 for you.

Comment: jquery selector i guess but unfortinatly there is nothing to select it on in this case

Comment: @nav , in what form of html you have text in the page , let us know , we can come up with better approach.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it. Let's suppose you need to do this on a h3 tag:

```
var h3tag = $('h3#head');
var txt = h3tag.text();
h3tag.text(''); //Remove default text
$("<a />", {
   "href" : $('h2 a').attr('href'), //grab the link from somewhere
   "text" : txt
}).appendTo(h3tag);
```

I hope it helps.